# Always get 'Could not find git repository' error when starting the gitg visual tool

Tags: git-gui

I click 'ok' then I can use

File -> Recently Opened or 
File -> New

But I cannot set a repository as the default and I cannot get rid of the startup message showing every time until I click 'OK'.

I am on Ubuntus 10 / 11  (gitg is the ubuntu equivalent of the Mac gitx tool)

Comment: How do you launch gitg? Command line, or otherwise? If it's via a menu, check the configuration and see if it's passed an argument (possibly the non-existent repo location).

Comment: Does it work with the command-line? If not, did you run git init?

Comment: opyate - no, through icon or from apps menu.

Comment: tjameson, All my git repositories work fine at the command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635966).

Here is a fairly lame workaround is for Ubuntu 10.10, I don't have any later version:
If you create a panel icon (by dragging the application icon to the panel for example), you can make it open a particular repository by editing its properties (right click -> Properties) and changing the "Command" field, replacing the %U with the path to your repository.

Comment: Hi Ergosys, thanks.  I tried playing around with that for about half an hour but no luck.  I'm on Ubuntu 11 and the way they changed the desktop and Unity launcher stuff was rather dramatic.  That said, I eventually managed to create the desktop launcher and it's command and the directories seems valid (/usr/bin/gitg /home/durrantm/Dropbox_not_syncd/webs/3/rubyists) but I still get the unknown repository error.

Comment: ok well I fiddled a little more and eventually got it to work.  I have both a script and an icon.  I can't get the icon in Unity to be other than a black square though. I'll give you the answer though for the help..